# SUM cost if Product ID is unique and matches multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have data in a sheet similar to the image. There are rows with duplicate Product ID information and I want to calculate the total cost of a unique Product that matches multiple criteria.

In this example, I want to calculate the cost where Type = Large and Version = A. The total in this example will be $30.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use QUERY and UNIQUE like this:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(A:D), "Select SUM(Col4)
   where Col2='Large' and Col3='A' 
   label SUM(Col4) 'Total'")
```

You can remove the label by replacing `'Total'` with `''` in the formula (no space between ticks).